# How do I code this panel layout on my webpage?

Tags: html, layout

What code should I use to layout my webpage as listed in this pic?

[image: Layout]

**Edit:** Unfortunately, this is not homework - I am just a web newb!! Thanks!

Comment: Props for including a nice diagram, instead of trying to explain it in words haha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are the height/weight of the boxes fixed or fluid? Has panel A any background?
The easiest way:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="side"> panel A</div>
    <div id="head"> panel B</div>
    <div id="content"> panel C</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
}
#side{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
#head{
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}
#content{
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}
```

If you have background to panel A, you should set it to the container, and inherit it from.

#### Edit:

Q: *How do I ensure that panel C doesn't slide under panel A when A's content is shorter/equal to Panel B?*
A: You have two option:
a) Wrap B and C to a wrapper div:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="side"> panel A</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="head"> panel B</div>
        <div id="content"> panel C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

b) Play with padding; set 20% padding to the container, and -20% margin to the side:

CSS

```
#container{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0 0 0 20%;
}
#side{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -20%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my follow-up, even after I deleted it!! I wish I could accept this answer again. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear whether you want fixed-width or floating-size "panels," but you can find tutorials for a wide range of HTML layouts using CSS at this website:

http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/page_layouts/

There are several varieties of two-column layouts.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%
}

div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#panela {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 98vh;
}
#panelb {
    float: right;
    width: 72%;
    height: 49vh;
}
#panelc {
    float:right;
    width: 72%;
    height: 49vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="panela">PANEL A</div>
<div id="panelb">PANEL B</div>
<div id="panelc">PANEL C</div>
```